# How to use horizontal scroll when you have way many columns

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to properly put the columns in proper place when you have many columns (like 15 columns).

Here is the screenshot for the web page I am doing.

[image: Here is the screenshot of the webpage]

As it can be seen, I am trying to do what trello(https://trello.com) does. When you have many columns, you will be able to scroll horizontally. But in here, the rest of the columns that do not fit to the page goes down to the page.

Here is the screenshot for trello, for what I want it to do

[image: Screenshot of trello]

As it can be seen on screenshot 2, It is able to scroll horizontally, no matter how many columns you have.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div id="background">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <h3>Objectives 1</h3>
            //content of cards here
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <h3>Objectives 2</h3>
            //content of cards here
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <h3>Objectives 3</h3>
            //content of cards here      
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <h3>Objectives 4</h3>
            //content of cards here
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <h3>Objectives 5</h3>
            //content of cards here
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <h3>Objectives 6</h3>
            //content of cards here
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <h3>Objectives 7</h3>
            //content of cards here
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <h3>Objectives 8</h3>
            //content of cards here
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <h3>Objectives 9</h3>
            //content of cards here
        </div>       
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS code:

```
#background
{ 
    background-color:#9B59B6;
    margin: -19px 0 0 0; //this is needed to remove the white space on top of the page
    min-height: 100vh; min-width: 100vw;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.col-sm-2 
{ 
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I am doing this on ASP.net MVC 6, it is in "cshtml" format, so I do think it is a bit different from html5.(I am a newbie)

I am new to web programming, how do I do this?

Please help, Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tables are one of the solutions to make page grow horizontally so when your using divs use these classes to simulate table behavior:

```css
#background
{ 
    background-color:#9B59B6;
    margin: -19px 0 0 0; 
    min-height: 100vh; min-width: 100vw;
    overflow:scroll;
    display:table;
}
.row
{ 
    display: table-row;
}
.col-sm-2 
{ 
    display: table-cell;
    padding:10px;
}
```

```html
    <div id="background">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <h3>Objectives 1</h3>
                //content of cards here
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <h3>Objectives 2</h3>
                //content of cards here
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <h3>Objectives 3</h3>
                //content of cards here
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <h3>Objectives 4</h3>
                //content of cards here
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <h3>Objectives 5</h3>
                //content of cards here
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <h3>Objectives 6</h3>
                //content of cards here
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <h3>Objectives 7</h3>
                //content of cards here
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <h3>Objectives 8</h3>
                //content of cards here
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <h3>Objectives 9</h3>
                //content of cards here
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <h3>Objectives 9</h3>
                //content of cards here
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <h3>Objectives 9</h3>
                //content of cards here
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <h3>Objectives 9</h3>
                //content of cards here
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <h3>Objectives 9</h3>
                //content of cards here
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <h3>Objectives 9</h3>
                //content of cards here
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <h3>Objectives 9</h3>
                //content of cards here
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <h3>Objectives 9</h3>
                //content of cards here
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <h3>Objectives 9</h3>
                //content of cards here
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <h3>Objectives 9</h3>
                //content of cards here
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

and you can also check this link its very useful:

> [How To Create a Horizontally Scrolling Site](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-a-horizontally-scrolling-site/)

Comment: This fix it! thanks man, But I had to put 'position:absolute' to fix it. But it really helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `overflow: hidden` to `overflow: auto` this should make it scrollable horizontally if width is bigger than screen and vertical if height is. 
if you want it to only be horizontally scrollable use  `overflow-x: auto`

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve that using css property flex.

```
.container{
  background:#587498;
  position:absolute;
}

.row {
  display:flex;
  display: -webkit-box;      
  display: -moz-box;         
  display: -ms-flexbox;     
  display: -webkit-flex;   
  flex-flow:row; 
  width:100%;  
}
.col {
  flex:1;
  -webkit-flex:1;
  margin:10px;
  padding:10px;
  background:#E86850;
  color:white;
  border:1px solid #FFD800;
}
```

[Working example here](http://forbootstrap.com/snippets/horizontal-scroll-with-flex)

Comment: Thanks, this is a much nicer looking example.

Answer (score 0):

make overflow-x:auto or scroll and you can restrict the vertical scroll by using overflow-y:hidden to the main container. Remember you should not use bootstraps predefined classes for this. You can also use flexboxes though which it is easy to implement this.